# using paste with read.csv inside a function

Tags: r, read.csv

I want to create a function that uses `read.csv()` with `paste()`.  The following code works in general

```
df <- read.csv(paste("/file name", 2010, ".CSV", sep = ""), header = TRUE)
```

but when I place it inside a function like so

```
myfunction <- function(date){df <- read.csv(
                             paste("/file name", date, ".CSV", sep = ""),
                             header = TRUE)
                            }
```

The command `myfunction(2010)` fails to produce output and does not result in any errors or warnings.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use <<- instead of <-

```
myfunction <- function(date){df <<- read.csv(
                             paste("/file name", date, ".CSV", sep = ""),
                             header = TRUE)
                            }
```

or you write:

```
myfunction <- function(date){read.csv(
                             paste("/file name", date, ".CSV", sep = ""),
                             header = TRUE)
                            }
df <- myfunction(2000)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always use sprintf

```
myfunction <- function(date){
  df <- read.csv(sprintf('/filename%s.csv',date))
  return(df)
}
csv <- myfunction(date)
```

and if you have lots of dates

```
ListDates <- as.list(dates)
ListOfCsvs <- lapply(ListDates,myfunction)
```

EDIT: I didnt make it clear that your issue was solved by `return(df)` inside `myfunction()`

Answer (score 0):

Return the dataframe from your function

```
myfunction <- function(date){
   df <- read.csv(paste("/file name", date, ".CSV", sep = ""),header = TRUE)
   return(df)
}
```

and assign it

```
df <- myfunction(2010)
```

In R, the last line in the function is automatically returned anyway, so this should also work.

```
myfunction <- function(date){
   read.csv(paste("/file name", date, ".CSV", sep = ""),header = TRUE)
}
```